# How to deinterlace GRAY video and convert it to .avi?

Tags: ffmpeg, avi

I have binary data stream from analogue camera and convert it to .avi with this

`λ ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt gray -s:v 700x220 -i orbita_d.bin -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p out.avi`

what do I need to deinterlace it? I read about yadiff, but it looks like it doesn't work with raw pixel data.

Comment: yadif, by default, relies on frame signaling to determine whether and how to deinterlace. A raw stream won't have those details, so you have to manually set them.

Answer (score -2):

`ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt gray -s:v 700x220 -i test1.bin -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt gray -vf tinterlace,setpts=0.5*PTS out.avi`

Do the trick for me.